# Opencart module_id not appending in admin link

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

I am developing a Opencart module (Version 4.0.0.0).

Created the module with height and status. Installed the same in the Opencart application. But the problem is when I tried to save the value to the db, it is creating a new row inside `"oc_module"` table. While checking I just found that `"module_id"` is not appending the URL from the module listing page's edit button.

The testimonial module link looks like

http://localhost/op4/admin/index.php?route=extension/testimonials/module/testimonials&user_token=2e7a4d8fad2e1c4339e9c01bc83d707a

extensions --> testimonial --> admin --> controller --> module --> testimonials.php

```
<?php
namespace Opencart\Admin\Controller\Extension\Testimonials\Module;
class Testimonials extends \Opencart\System\Engine\Controller {
    public function index(): void {
        $this->load->language('extension/testimonials/module/testimonials');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));
        $this->load->model('setting/setting');
        $data['breadcrumbs'] = [];

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = [
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/dashboard', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'])
        ];

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = [
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_extension'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('marketplace/extension', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'] . '&type=module')
        ];

        if (!isset($this->request->get['module_id'])) {
            $data['breadcrumbs'][] = [
                'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
                'href' => $this->url->link('extension/testimonials/module/testimonials', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'])
            ];
        } else {
            $data['breadcrumbs'][] = [
                'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
                'href' => $this->url->link('extension/testimonials/module/testimonials', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'] . '&module_id=' . $this->request->get['module_id'])
            ];
        }

        if (!isset($this->request->get['module_id'])) {
            $data['save'] = $this->url->link('extension/testimonials/module/testimonials|save', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token']);
        } else {
            $data['save'] = $this->url->link('extension/testimonials/module/testimonials|save', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'] . '&module_id=' . $this->request->get['module_id']);
        }

        $data['back'] = $this->url->link('marketplace/extension', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'] . '&type=module');

        if (isset($this->request->get['module_id'])) {
                $this->load->model('setting/module');

            $module_info = $this->model_setting_module->getModule($this->request->get['module_id']);
            print_r($module_info);
        }

        
        if (isset($module_info['name'])) {
            $data['name'] = $module_info['name'];
        } else {
            $data['name'] = '';
        }


        if (isset($module_info['height'])) {
            $data['height'] = $module_info['height'];
        } else {
            $data['height'] = 200;
        }

        if (isset($module_info['status'])) {
            $data['status'] = $module_info['status'];
        } else {
            $data['status'] = '';
        }

        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('extension/testimonials/module/testimonials', $data));
    }

    public function save(): void {
        $this->load->language('extension/testimonials/module/testimonials');

        $json = [];

        if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'extension/testimonials/module/testimonials')) {
            $json['error']['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
        }

        
        if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name']) > 64)) {
            $json['error']['name'] = $this->language->get('error_name');
        }
        if (!$this->request->post['height']) {
            $json['error']['height'] = $this->language->get('error_height');
        }

        if (!$json) {
            $this->load->model('setting/module');
            if (!isset($this->request->get['module_id'])) {
                $this->model_setting_module->addModule('module_testimonials', $this->request->post);
            } else {
                $this->model_setting_module->editModule($this->request->get['module_id'], $this->request->post);
            }

            

            $json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');
        }
    

        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your save function.
You need to change: $this->model_setting_module->addModule('module_testimonials', $this->request->post);
to:
$this->model_setting_module->addModule('testimonials.testimonials', $this->request->post);